# how to select rows adjacent to blank cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

In the excel sheet, I have two columns A and B. For every value in rows in column A there are values in column B. But some of the rows in column B are blank because of unavailability of value for the value in column A.

Now I want to pick only the row values in column A for which corresponding row in column B are blank. How do i do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub filterBlanks()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="

        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) to find hte blanks in column B and then [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to select their corresponding cells from column A.

```
with activesheet
    with .columns("B").specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks)
        with .offset(0, -1)
            .select 'do something with the cells in column A
        end with
    end with
end with
```

The above can have problems if you have cells merged across columns A and B (e.g. A1:B1 are merged). It also depends upon the cells being truly blank; not cells with formulas returning zero-length strings (which are not blank cells).

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. Works perfectly.